# startActivity(intent) not working when used along with data binding

Tags: android, android-intent, data-binding

I have used data binding in my code. On using data binding `startActivity(intent)` is not taking me to the `SecondActivity`

MainActivity.java -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private Data data = new Data();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setData(data);
        binding.invalidateAll();

        data.setClickMe("Click Me");

        binding.button.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

SeondActivity.java -

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private Data data = new Data();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_second);
        binding.setData(data);
        binding.invalidateAll();
        data.setHelloThere("Hello there");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is any error, displaying in logcat?

Comment: add a logcat error here.

Comment: How to get logcat error? I am new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I have made a silly mistake here

In `SecondActivity.java` -

on second line it should be -

`private ActivitySecondBinding binding`

rather than

`private ActivityMainBinding binding`